# Das ist er ja - ambiguity

Tags: particle

Im folgenden Satz:

Da ist er ja, John Barrymore.
   = There he is, John Barrymore

Ich denke, dass "ja" nach Duden hier bedeutet:

Drückt im Aussagesatz eine resümierende Feststellung aus, weist auf etwas Bekanntes hin oder dient der Begründung für ein nicht explizites Geschehen oder für etwas Allgemeingültiges; doch, bekanntlich

Jedoch das scheint mir mehrdeutig. Ich gebe einige hypothetische Fälle an, um es zu veranschaulichen:

a) John ist ein Freund vom Sprecher.

Woher weiß der Zuhörer, ob "ja" "von mir bekannt", "von meiner Familie bekannt", "von all unseren Freunden bekannt" oder etwas anderes bedeutet?

b) John ist ein berühmter australischer Schauspieler, der im seinem Land sehr bekannt ist, im Ausland jedoch nicht. Der Sprecher und der Zuhörer leben in Deutschland.

Woher weiß der Zuhörer, ob "ja" "von unserem Land bekannt", "von seiner Land bekannt", "von der ganzen Welt bekannt" oder etwas anderes bedeutet?

Answer (score 2):

Die Beschreibung des Beispiels bezieht sich nur auf "weist auf etwas Bekanntes hin", diesen Fall sehe ich im vorliegenden Satz allerdings nicht.
Die alleinige Antwort auf deine Frage wäre, niemand weiß etwas über die Bekanntheit, denn die Annahme ist nicht korrekt.
Ich möchte trotzdem erklären wie ich dieses "ja" interpretiere.  Es ist mehr oder weniger ein Füllwort, das nicht direkt übersetzt werden kann.

Das "er" in "da ist **er** ja" drückt aus dass bereits zuvor über John gesprochen wurde. Sonst würde man den Satz nicht mit "da ist er ja" beginnen, sondern nur sagen "da ist ja John".
Das "ja" drückt die Überraschung aus, dass der gerade erwähnte John nun zufällig in diesem Moment zum Sprecher und seinem Gesprächspartner kommt.
Der Satz bedeutet also: "Oh so eine Überraschung, genau das ist zufälligerweise dieser John, von dem ich gerade erzählt habe".
Ob alle anderen John auch kennen oder nur ich, ist dabei nicht von Bedeutung.

Comment: Es wurde nicht zuvor über John gesprochen, sondern über "er". *Mein Bekannter ist übrigens ein berühmter Schauspieler. Da ist er ja. / Da ist **mein Bekannter** ja.*

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht genau, was du meintest, @Janka. Geht es darum, wenn der Name der Person (John Barrymore) vor dem Satz explizit erwähnt wurde?

Comment: @puck Wenn "ja" hier eine Überraschung ausdrückt (Bedeutung 3b in Duden), würde diese Partikel in diesem Satz nicht verwendet, wenn der Sprecher den Hörer mitgenommen hätte, um John irgendwo zu treffen?

Comment: @Alan Evangelista: Obwohl ich diese Antwort eigentlich schon gut finde, werde ich selbst eine eigene Antwort schreiben, denn für einen bloßen Kommentar werden meine Ausführungen zu lang.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Auch dann könnte man "ja" verwenden. Wenn man John gezielt treffen will, ist es nicht überraschend ihn an diesem Ort zu sehen. Das "ja" kann trotzdem ausdrücken dass man John jetzt zufällig (auf den aktuellen Zeitpunkt bezogen) sieht: "also, da ist John". Für genauere Überlegungen müsste der Kontext bekannt sein.

Comment: @puck Ich glaube, dass ein "ja" in deinem Beispiel im letzten Kommentar fehlt ? Außerdem verstehe ich nicht genau , was du mit "zufällig" meintest. Früher als erwartet? Und welches Gefühl drückt "ja" in diesem Fall aus?

Comment: Mit zufällig meine ich,es ist nicht genau bekannt wann oder wo wir John sehen werden. Wenn ich weiß dass John in 5 Sekunden an mir vorbei läuft oder dass er an einer bestimmten Stelle stehen wird, verwende ich kein "ja". Dann ist es eher überraschend wenn John **nicht** kam oder an der erwarteten Stelle war. In diesem Fall könnte ich später zu John sagen "du warst ja doch nicht da". Das drückt das unerwartete Ereignis aus. Ein bestimmtes Gefühl erkenne ich dahinter nicht. Es kann sowohl Freude oder Abneigung sein, oder auch neutral.

Answer (score 2):

Das Wörtchen **ja** ist in diesem Fall ein Modalpartikel. Modalpartikel wabern wie Nebel über dem Satz und tauchen ihn in eine bestimmte Stimmung.

> Da liegen meine Schlüssel.

Ich stelle fest, dass dort meine Schlüssel liegen.

> Da liegen ja meine Schlüssel.
>
> Da liegen meine Schlüssel ja.

Ich stelle **zu meiner Überraschung** fest, dass dort meine Schlüssel liegen. Die zweite Variante hat den Partikel in der hervorgehobenen Position am Satzende. Meine Überraschung ist also noch etwas größer.

Dein Beispiel-Sachverhalt ist leider etwas komplizierter. Eine mögliche vorhergehende Szene wäre, dass du deinem Gesprächspartner erzählt hast, dein Freund sei ein bekannter Schauspieler. Dein Gesprächspartner glaubt dir das nicht so recht, und du zeigst auf jemanden, der gerade aus dem Zug steigt, mit diesen Worten:

> Da ist er **ja**, John Barrymore.

Es ist irrelevant, ob dein Gesprächspartner John Barrymore überhaupt kennt. Die Überraschung bezieht sich darauf, dass diese Person, über die ihr eben gerade gesprochen habt, gerade in diesem Moment aus dem Zug steigt.